# Copy groupby().agg to each row

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am looking for a way to copy the result of an aggregate call to each row in a dataframe.

I am currently doing it like this:

```
tmp = df.groupby('somekey').col_to_sum.sum().reset_index()
df = df.merge(tmp, how='left', on='somekey')
```

This gives me the result I want:
`tmp` is a series of the sum for each value of `somekey` and the merge then "copies it" to each row in the original `df` (so each row contains the sum value).

Is there a shorter way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Use `transform`.... `df['newcol'] =df.groupby('somekey').col_to_sum.transform('sum')`

Comment: Thanks. The duplicate above is also itself a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949020/best-way-to-add-group-totals-to-a-dataframe-in-pandas :) It's interesting how each question is worded in completely different ways...

Comment: Yes... does this help?  If not, you can edit the question a bit, and we'll try to help.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the solution I was looking for, thanks for answering!