# Add aggregated/summary lines in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2018,'R1','C1',1],[2018,'R1','C2',2],[2018,'R1','C3',3],[2018,'R1','C4',4],[2018,'R1','C5',5],[2018,'R2','C6',6],[2018,'R2','C7',7],[2018,'R2','C8',8],[2018,'R2','C9',9],[2018,'R2','C10',10]]),columns=['Year', 'Region', 'Country', 'Spend'])
```

I'd like to add summary lines to each possible `group by` (`groups`) so that the output dataframe looks something like this:

[image]

I have learned how to add summary/total lines as a column based on this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30949063). But I would like to have these total lines merged to the original data frame as show in the above screenshot and I would like to accomplish this in as few lines as possible (that is, avoiding having to call different `groupby` combinations manually like below):

```
df['ByYearTotalCount'] = df.groupby(['Year'])['Spend'].transform('sum')
df['ByYearByRegionTotalCount'] = df.groupby(['Year','Region'])['Spend'].transform('sum')
```

Could anyone help me come up with the best `pandas`-like way to accomplish this? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` to get the Total/Subtotal rows first and `concat` the result dataframes

```py
df2 = df.groupby(['Year'])['Spend'].sum().reset_index()
df3 = df.groupby(['Year', 'Region'])['Spend'].sum().reset_index()
df = pd.concat([df, df2, df3], sort=False).fillna('All').sort_values(by=['Region', 'Country'])
```

**Output**

```py
df2
   Year  Spend
0  2018     55

df3
   Year Region  Spend
0  2018     R1     15
1  2018     R2     40

df
   Year Region Country  Spend
0  2018    All     All     55
0  2018     R1     All     15
0  2018     R1      C1      1
1  2018     R1      C2      2
2  2018     R1      C3      3
3  2018     R1      C4      4
4  2018     R1      C5      5
1  2018     R2     All     40
9  2018     R2     C10     10
5  2018     R2      C6      6
6  2018     R2      C7      7
7  2018     R2      C8      8
8  2018     R2      C9      9
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing a similar thing but using `append`. But your suggested solution looks neat. I'm accepting it because it does the job that I wanted. Thank you again.