# How to create new columns in pandas depending on multiple conditions and by grouping to calculate previous costs and cumulative cost?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm relatively new to Pandas and after searching here for solutions I have not been able to find anything that translates well to my problem.

I have a DataFrame like this (df_transactions):

```
 col_type      col_ticker      col_transacted_value
 'buy'         'TSLA'          '100'                           
 'buy'         'TSLA'          '100'                           
 'buy'         'TSLA'          '100'                           
 'sell'        'TSLA'          '300'                              
 ...           ...             ...
```

And I would like to create two new columns, with the cumulative previous costs and cumulative costs.

To get the previous cost I have used:

```
df_transactions[col_prev_cost] = df_transactions.groupby(col_ticker)[col_transacted_value].shift().fillna(0)
```

but then realized this only finds the previous occurrence of that ticker and populate a new column with it´s transacted_costs.

My idea is too group by ticker and depending on the value of col_type populate a new column 'col_prev_costs', and with that column create the new column 'cml_cost'. Or if you see a simpler way - do share!

I want it to operate like this:

```
 col_type      col_ticker      col_transacted_value        New_col_prev_cost       New_col_cml_cost
 'buy'         'TSLA'          '100'                       '0'                     '100'
 'buy'         'TSLA'          '100'                       '100'                   '200'
 'buy'         'TSLA'          '100'                       '200'                   '300'
 'sell'        'TSLA'          '300'                       '300'                   '0'     
 ...           ...             ...                         ...                      ...
```

I'm open to all suggestions!

Thanks in advance! / Jakob

---

**UPDATE: My first question was somewhat flawed so I will try to explain it again.**

I have now discovered that I missed the correct handling of transactions with sell type, as this is dependent on even previous holdings of the ticker.

Let´s say I have the given dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the dataframe:
data = {'date'              : ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04'],
        'ticker'            : ['TSLA','TSLA', 'TSLA', 'TSLA', 'TSLA', 'TSLA', 'TSLA', 'AAPL', 'AAPL'],
        'type'              : ['buy', 'buy', 'split', 'sell', 'buy', 'sell', 'buy', 'buy', 'buy'],
        'units'             : [2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2.5, 4],
        'price'             : [50.5, 50.5, 0, 52, 35, 52, 35, 50.5, 50.5],
        'fees'              : [4, 4, 0, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 3, 1.5, 2],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
Out[2]: 
         date ticker   type  units  price  fees
0  2022-01-01   TSLA    buy    2.0   50.5   4.0
1  2022-01-02   TSLA    buy    2.0   50.5   4.0
2  2022-01-02   TSLA  split    3.0    0.0   0.0
3  2022-01-03   TSLA   sell    2.0   52.0   2.5
4  2022-01-03   TSLA    buy    2.0   35.0   3.0
5  2022-01-03   TSLA   sell    2.0   52.0   2.5
6  2022-01-03   TSLA    buy    2.0   35.0   3.0
7  2022-01-03   AAPL    buy    2.5   50.5   1.5
8  2022-01-04   AAPL    buy    4.0   50.5   2.0
```

Whereas I calculate the following columns:

```
# Create the column transaction value

def calc_transaction_value(type_transaction, price_unit, transacted_units, fees):
    """
    Calculate the transaction value from three columns in a dataframe depending on the value of type.
    """
    if type_transaction == 'buy':
        return price_unit * transacted_units + fees # i.e. the transacted cost
    if type_transaction == 'sell':
        return price_unit * transacted_units - fees # i.e. the gross income of capital
    else:
        return np.nan # If other return filler return NA (i.e. not available)

df['transacted_value'] = df.apply(lambda x: calc_transaction_value(x['type'], x['price'], x['units'], x['fees']), axis=1).fillna(0)

df
Out[3]: 
         date ticker   type  units  price  fees  transacted_value
0  2022-01-01   TSLA    buy    2.0   50.5   4.0            105.00
1  2022-01-02   TSLA    buy    2.0   50.5   4.0            105.00
2  2022-01-02   TSLA  split    3.0    0.0   0.0              0.00
3  2022-01-03   TSLA   sell    2.0   52.0   2.5            101.50
4  2022-01-03   TSLA    buy    2.0   35.0   3.0             73.00
5  2022-01-03   TSLA   sell    2.0   52.0   2.5            101.50
6  2022-01-03   TSLA    buy    2.0   35.0   3.0             73.00
7  2022-01-03   AAPL    buy    2.5   50.5   1.5            127.75
8  2022-01-04   AAPL    buy    4.0   50.5   2.0            204.00
```

```
# create the flow of units, depends on transaction type (buy or sell)
df["flow_units"] = df.apply(lambda x: -x["units"] if x["type"] == "sell" else x["units"], axis=1)

# Create the cml_units and prev_units column
df = df.groupby("ticker").apply(lambda grp: grp.assign(cml_units=grp["flow_units"].cumsum().abs(),
                                                           prev_units=grp["flow_units"].shift(1).cumsum().abs().fillna(0)))
df
Out[4]: 
         date ticker   type  units  price  fees  transacted_value  flow_units  \
0  2022-01-01   TSLA    buy    2.0   50.5   4.0            105.00         2.0   
1  2022-01-02   TSLA    buy    2.0   50.5   4.0            105.00         2.0   
2  2022-01-02   TSLA  split    3.0    0.0   0.0              0.00         3.0   
3  2022-01-03   TSLA   sell    2.0   52.0   2.5            101.50        -2.0   
4  2022-01-03   TSLA    buy    2.0   35.0   3.0             73.00         2.0   
5  2022-01-03   TSLA   sell    2.0   52.0   2.5            101.50        -2.0   
6  2022-01-03   TSLA    buy    2.0   35.0   3.0             73.00         2.0   
7  2022-01-03   AAPL    buy    2.5   50.5   1.5            127.75         2.5   
8  2022-01-04   AAPL    buy    4.0   50.5   2.0            204.00         4.0   

   cml_units  prev_units  
0        2.0         0.0  
1        4.0         2.0  
2        7.0         4.0  
3        5.0         7.0  
4        7.0         5.0  
5        5.0         7.0  
6        7.0         5.0  
7        2.5         0.0  
8        6.5         2.5
```

Where this is from the help I got from the previous comment @SRawson.

But here I would like to create the columns `prev_costs`, `cml_costs` and `cost_transaction`. The logic is as follows:

I want to for each row, get the ticker from column `"ticker"`, and:

- if transaction type value is equal to `"buy"` in column `"type"` then compute the operation `"prev_costs + transacted_value"` and populate in column `"cml_costs"`.

  - Where `"prev_costs"` for that row is `"cml_costs"` but shifted one row up (if grouped by ticker).
- if transaction type value is equal to `"sell"` then compute the operation `"prev_costs - cost_transaction"` and populate in `"cml_costs"`.

  - Where `"prev_costs"` for that row is `"cml_costs"` but shifted one row up (if grouped by ticker).
  - And where `"cost_transaction"` is the result of operation (for that row): `(units/cml_units) * prev_costs`
- else return `"prev_costs"` and populate in `"cml_costs"`.

I expect the dataframe:

```
data_2 = {'prev_costs'           : [0, 105, 210, 210, 150, 223, 159.29, 0, 127.75],
          'cml_costs'            : [105, 210, 210, 150, 223, 159.29, 232.29, 127.75, 331.75],
          'cost_transaction'     : [0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 63.71, 0, 0, 0],
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)

df_expected = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1, join='inner')

df_expected
Out[5]: 
         date ticker   type  units  price  fees  transacted_value  flow_units  \
0  2022-01-01   TSLA    buy    2.0   50.5   4.0            105.00         2.0   
1  2022-01-02   TSLA    buy    2.0   50.5   4.0            105.00         2.0   
2  2022-01-02   TSLA  split    3.0    0.0   0.0              0.00         3.0   
3  2022-01-03   TSLA   sell    2.0   52.0   2.5            101.50        -2.0   
4  2022-01-03   TSLA    buy    2.0   35.0   3.0             73.00         2.0   
5  2022-01-03   TSLA   sell    2.0   52.0   2.5            101.50        -2.0   
6  2022-01-03   TSLA    buy    2.0   35.0   3.0             73.00         2.0   
7  2022-01-03   AAPL    buy    2.5   50.5   1.5            127.75         2.5   
8  2022-01-04   AAPL    buy    4.0   50.5   2.0            204.00         4.0   

   cml_units  prev_units  prev_costs  cml_costs  cost_transaction  
0        2.0         0.0        0.00     105.00              0.00  
1        4.0         2.0      105.00     210.00              0.00  
2        7.0         4.0      210.00     210.00              0.00  
3        5.0         7.0      210.00     150.00             60.00  
4        7.0         5.0      150.00     223.00              0.00  
5        5.0         7.0      223.00     159.29             63.71  
6        7.0         5.0      159.29     232.29              0.00  
7        2.5         0.0        0.00     127.75              0.00  
8        6.5         2.5      127.75     331.75              0.00
```

I was not sure if it is okey to "update" a question in such a major way, but hopes it is. Please comment if this is wrong from my part.

I have made this work in google sheets, but as I said in the first question I'm quite new to pandas and in desperate need for help again.

Thanks in advance (again)!

Comment: Can you explain the logic for calculating `New_col_prev_cost `?

Comment: Yes absolutely! Calculation of New_col_prev_cost should: for each row, find the same ticker (in the ticker column) and depending on the transaction type in col_type  sum or subtract the value in col_transacted_value (i.e we get the cumulative sum of the buy transaction subtracted by the cumulative sum of the sell transaction  from the prev entry). Then populate a new column named New_col_prev_cost.

Comment: There might be another solution by calculating new_col_cml_cost first by, finding the cumsum by ticker of the col_transacted_value by col_type 'buy' and then by sell and calculate the difference and populate the New_col_cml_cost column. Then use that to create the New_col_prev_cost column from col_transacted_value and New_col_cml_cost. Hope I did explain it somewhat okey.

Comment: So the 'New_col_prev_cost' should show me the transacted cumulative value of that  from previous entry of that ticker :)  @ShubhamSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col_type": ["buy", "buy", "buy", "sell", "buy", "sell", "buy"],
                        "col_ticker": ["TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL"],
                        "col_transacted_value": ["100", "100", "100", "300", "150", "200", "100"]})

df["col_transacted_value"] = df["col_transacted_value"].astype(int)
df["col_transacted_value_signs"] = df.apply(lambda x: -x["col_transacted_value"] if x["col_type"] == "sell" else x["col_transacted_value"], axis=1)
df = df.groupby("col_ticker").apply(lambda grp: grp.assign(New_col_cml_cost=grp["col_transacted_value_signs"].cumsum(),
                                                           New_col_prev_cost=grp["col_transacted_value_signs"].shift(1).cumsum().fillna(0)))
```

The explanation:

- Convert your string values to integers (else floats if you will
  not always have integers).
- Create a new column with -ve
  values for "sell" and +ve for "buy" (you could overwrite the
  `col_transacted_value` column if you don't need all items to be +ve.
- Finally, group by `col_ticker` and assign the new columns using apply
  lambda.

I took inspiration for the groupby apply assign idea from this comment from [krassowski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200693/python-pandas-how-to-assign-groupby-operation-results-back-to-columns-in-parent#:%7E:text=df.groupby(%27yearmonth%27).apply(lambda%20grp%3A%20grp.assign(mkt_return%3Dgrp%5B%27return%27%5D.sum()))).

Output (TSLA is like your example):

```
#Out: 
#             col_type col_ticker  ...  New_col_cml_cost  New_col_prev_cost
#col_ticker                        ...                                     
#AAPL       4      buy       AAPL  ...               150                0.0
#           5     sell       AAPL  ...               -50              150.0
#           6      buy       AAPL  ...                50              -50.0
#TSLA       0      buy       TSLA  ...               100                0.0
#           1      buy       TSLA  ...               200              100.0
#           2      buy       TSLA  ...               300              200.0
#           3     sell       TSLA  ...                 0              300.0
#
#[7 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer and solution @SRawson. I really only have one thought and that is if it is common practice to create "temporary columns", i.e. columns I don´t have a direct use of (e.g. the column for "col_transacted_value_signs") and is it problematic to do this and thus should it be avoided? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you.  That's a very interesting question, one I haven't ever thought of or seen a discussion on before.  I don't think it is too common to create a single column that is not used much, I tend to see new dataframes created more frequently, and already-existing columns changed.  I only think it would be a problem if you were returning the dataframe to be viewed by a user, and even then it would be easy to exclude the column.  However, I don't think I am the most conventional user of Python, so don't take my word as final!

Comment: Was there a problem with the code that caused you to "unaccept" this solution?

Comment: Your answer was excellent, nothing wrong at all. When I updated the question (which I'm a little unsure if it's allowed) I was unsure if I should keep the label as accepted due to it is linked to it. I'm terribly sorry and was not meant as an insult, as I was unsure what the custom was if the question is updated. For some reason I tought it was meant for labelling a question as "complete", but of course I change back and thank you for the clarification of the label. :)

Comment: No problem at all.  I just wanted to make sure something hadn't suddenly gone wrong!