# While using groupby, set column to value from some row within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df setup similar to the one below. Each Date and Ticker combo only has the Bool flip to 1 on one row.

| Date | Ticker | High | Low | Bool |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-20 | AAPL | 146 | 144 | 0 |
| 2023-02-20 | AAPL | 143 | 142 | 0 |
| 2023-02-20 | AAPL | 144 | 143 | 1 |
| 2023-02-20 | MSFT | 146 | 144 | 0 |
| 2023-02-20 | MSFT | 143 | 142 | 1 |
| 2023-02-20 | MSFT | 144 | 143 | 0 |
| 2023-02-21 | AAPL | 146 | 144 | 0 |
| 2023-02-21 | AAPL | 143 | 142 | 1 |
| 2023-02-21 | AAPL | 144 | 143 | 0 |

I want to create a new column where the entire column is equal to the High where the Bool turns to 1, when grouped by Date and Ticker.

So the output df would look like the following:

| Date | Ticker | High | Low | Bool | New_Row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-20 | AAPL | 146 | 144 | 0 | 144 |
| 2023-02-20 | AAPL | 143 | 142 | 0 | 144 |
| 2023-02-20 | AAPL | 144 | 143 | 1 | 144 |
| 2023-02-20 | MSFT | 251 | 248 | 0 | 252 |
| 2023-02-20 | MSFT | 252 | 251 | 1 | 252 |
| 2023-02-20 | MSFT | 255 | 250 | 0 | 252 |
| 2023-02-21 | AAPL | 146 | 144 | 0 | 143 |
| 2023-02-21 | AAPL | 143 | 142 | 1 | 143 |
| 2023-02-21 | AAPL | 144 | 143 | 0 | 143 |

I am unsure of how to do this without just looping through everything manually and I'm thinking that it's probably not the best way to go about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a new column named `High_times_Bool`:

```
df['High_times_Bool']=df['High']*df['Bool']
```

Then you may group by `Date`, `Ticker` and select the max `High_times_Bool` for each sub group:

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Ticker'])['High_time_Bool'].max()
```

Finally you may inject the output values back into the original dataframe, following the logic outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201723/6440589).